# TeXstudio syntax highlighting for Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio, syntax-highlighting, syntax-checker

How can I get in TeXstudio the same syntax highlighting of TikzEdt?
Look at the red word (called operation in Tikz, I think) "circle".

In TikzEdt:

[image: TikzEdt syntax highlighting]

In TeXstudio:

[image]

Comment: You probably need to write your own language definition: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#LANGUAGEDEF

Comment: @Troy In TikzEdt is present the file "TikzSyntax.xshd". Do you think it can be adapted for the task?

Comment: Hm, the syntax is a little different (after a quick glance at the file -- it's my first time seeing `tikzsyntax.xshd`), but certainly possible. I don't have time to look into it now, but maybe in the next few days... In the meantime you could give it a shot yourself.

Comment: @Troy In TXS manual that you link there is written: "_You can add your own languages or overwrite the default ones by placing appropriate .qnfa files in a languages folder inside the settings directory._" **First**: where is the setting folder in windows? **Second**:  Do I must even ricompile the TXS code? Or is it enough put the .qnfa file in the settings directory?

Comment: Put the `.qnfa` in `.\TeXstudio\config\languages` folder. And if you also want to add your own format, you need to define it inside a `.qxf` file and place it in that same folder (or just edit the `defaultformats.qxf` file). Though, [this discussion](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/141#issue-322496656) might be of interest to you as well. Like the manual said, these are extra experimental features, so there's little support from the devs for these.

Comment: Settings folder: see https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#where-are-the-settings-stored

Comment: @Troy Thanks for your assistence. In my installation of TeXstudio 2.12.8 (hg 2.12.8-1-g68cd350), the folder that contain the `textstudio.ini` is in `C:\Users\ _<myName>_ \AppData\Roaming\texstudio\`.

Answer (score 5):

I got the desired result.

[image: Syntax Hightlighting as tikzEdt]

For some strange reason, `circle` is highlighted as a grammatical error,  that disappears if I select the dictionary in English (I'm italian).
It is not a big deal.

I'm not being able to create a working `.qxf` file. I've create the file and put it in the folder where there is the `texstudio.ini` file, as suggested by Troy, but it don't work.
Even the file `.qnfa` that I've create didn't work, when put in the same folder.
So, how did I do it?
I've download the `tex.qnfa` from the [TXS's SourgeForge host](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/hg/ci/default/tree/utilities/qxs/), then I add the following code to this file:

```
    <!-- ========================= tikzPICTURES ====================== -->
    <context id="tikzpicture" format="picture" transparency="true"> 
        <start parenthesis="tikzpicture:open@nocomplete" parenthesisWeight="30" fold="1" format="extra-keyword">\\begin{tikzpicture}</start>
        <stop parenthesis="tikzpicture:close@nocomplete" parenthesisWeight="30" fold="1" format="extra-keyword">\\end{tikzpicture}</stop>
        <sequence id="tikzpicture/keyword" ambiguous="true" format="lua:comment">\\[a-zA-Z@]+</sequence>
        <word id="tikzpicture/operation" ambiguous="true" format="lua:keyword">circle</word>
        <word id="tikzpicture/operation" ambiguous="true" format="lua:keyword">coordinate</word>
        <word id="tikzpicture/operation" ambiguous="true" format="lua:keyword">grid</word>
        <word id="tikzpicture/operation" ambiguous="true" format="lua:keyword">rectangle</word>
        <word id="tikzpicture/operation" ambiguous="true" format="lua:keyword">ellipse</word>
        <word id="tikzpicture/operation" ambiguous="true" format="lua:keyword">edge</word>
        <word id="tikzpicture/operation" ambiguous="true" format="lua:keyword">--</word>
        <word id="tikzpicture/operation" ambiguous="true" format="lua:keyword">at</word>
        <word id="tikzpicture/operation" ambiguous="true" format="lua:keyword">to</word>
        <word id="tikzpicture/operation" ambiguous="true" format="lua:keyword">node</word>
        <word id="tikzpicture/operation" ambiguous="true" format="lua:keyword">-|</word>
        <word id="tikzpicture/operation" ambiguous="true" format="lua:keyword">|-</word>
    </context>
```

and put this file in the previous mentioned folder before the block of code that define the Syntax Highlighthing of PICTURES. It's possible put this code even after the PICTURES block, if you delete `<e>tikzpicture</e>` from the PICTURES block of code. 
Since I'm not succeed to create a working `.qxf` file I've used the format of `lua:keyword` suitably setted (`Options > TeXstudio setting... > Syntax Hightligthing`. I've set the color to `a52a2a`, that is the red-brown used in TikzEdt for `circle`, `rectangle` etc., and that's all.

I do not understand why a `.qnfa` file with only the part that I added to the file `tex.qnfa` does not work. Therefore I'm not very satisfied by the result. Please correct my prose, I don't speak english very well.

Comment: Meanwhile I'm doing all this trial on the `tex.qnfa` I find that in this file there is a repeated block at line nr 161 and 194 in all of which there is, I think, a syntax error `prenthesisweight` instead of `parenthesisWeight`