# Making TeXstudio syntax highlighting recognize a custom verbatim environment

Tags: texstudio, verbatim, syntax-highlighting

I'm using TeXstudio for pretty much all my LaTeX needs.

I sometimes have to include small code snippets in a document where employing the `listings` package would be overkill. Since I'd like for these to have a colored background (which is not supported by the standard `verbatim` environment of course), I'm defining a new environment using the `tcolorbox` and `fancyvrb` packages, as suggested by @egreg in [this excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163421/158639):

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
% ...
\newenvironment{BGVerbatim}
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, colback = Dandelion!10!white, spartan, frame hidden, boxrule = 0pt, left = 1ex]%
  \begin{Verbatim}}
 {\end{Verbatim}\end{tcolorbox}}
```

This works fine, but if you include e.g. R code that includes `$` characters, TeXstudio's syntax highlighting gets confused, which is especially problematic in large documents where thousands of subsequent lines may get wrongly highlighted as if in math mode.

Comment: I've had a partial success in create a syntax highlighting for tikzpicture with the technique described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433281/162128)

Comment: What about use R to show R code? The keyword is `knitr`. See for instance [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307265/11604), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240489/11604) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576340/11604).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. knitr is not suitable for longer documents that are 95% -- well -- document, and 5% code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is to define a custom syntax highlighting hints (`.cwl`) file for TeXstudio. The TeXstudio manual has [more information](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION) about the format of these files; all that is needed here is the following:

```
\begin{BGVerbatim}#V
\end{BGVerbatim}#V
```

which declares the `BGVerbatim` environment to be of `verbatim`-type (`#V`).

This should be put into a filed called e.g. `CUSTOM.cwl`, which in turn should be placed in the appropriate user directory: `%APPDATA%\texstudio\completion\user` on Windows, `.config/texstudio/completion/user` on Linux and other Unix-like OSes (I presume this includes MacOS X).

Afterward, enable this syntax highlighting file by selecting `Options > Configure TeXstudio ...` and navigating to the `Completion` tab:

[image]

Click on `OK`; you may have to restart TeXstudio for your document to be correctly highlighted (I did).

The downside to this approach is that this highlighting will always be active even when the `BGVerbatim` environment is not defined in a document, but I do not consider this to be relevant in practice.

A more substantial downside is that this solution is specific to the computer the document is being edited on; if the document is shared, every computer used will have to be configured accordingly. Regrettably, there appears to be no way to embed TeXstudio syntax highlighting hints in `.tex` files themselves (using magic comments of some sort).